# Master volume of device on WP7 device

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to adjust the master  volume of phone in wp7 mango update, or switch between sound / vibration / silence? I would like to create an application that would change the profile depending on conditions. Thank you for your reply :-D

Comment: It is up to user. I would be pissed if some app turns from vibration to sound while I'm at the meeting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cant. In 7.1(mango), The API does not allow it (and for very good reason as lukas stated in your comment. I dont ever think they will allow you to do this either.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your reply. On Windows Mobile 6.5 I used a similar application and I used it a lot. Well, never mind:)